# Odata $filter always returns empty array with node js and postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, odata

I want to create a simple REST endpoint with OData and the $filter parameter.
This is my filter query param: `$filter=shoecolor eq 'black'`

And this is my node js code:

```
import { createFilter } from "odata-v4-pg";
...
   var filter = createFilter(req.query.$filter + "");            
   const projectName = req.params.projectname;
   const storeName = req.params.storename; 
 
   this.logger.info(filter.where);      // prints: "shoecolor" = $1         

   var result = await this.database.any(`SELECT * FROM $1:name.$2:name WHERE ${filter.where}`, [projectName, storeName]);
   this.logger.info(result);           // prints an empty array!!!
...
```

Why is my SELECT with OData $filter always empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own: I forgot to pass filter.parameters to the query. This link gives a good example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-pg?activeTab=readme