# Convert OData filter Query to SQL Where Statement in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5

We have a requirement that require OData filter to be converted into SQL where clause.
Performing String operation won't help as field values can have standard keywords

I didn't find any standard library in Node.js which can help us.

tried below npm libraries but nothing seems to help

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-sql?activeTab=code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-sql?activeTab=code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-query-sql
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mocobaas/odata-filter-to-sql?activeTab=code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-filter-parser?activeTab=readme
```

can anyone please help ..

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: this answer from might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560057/odata-filter-always-returns-empty-array-with-node-js-and-postgresql

Comment: Have you tried a custom solution?